# Different solutions for an equation

Tags: plotting, equation-solving, export, nonlinear, difference-equations

I have a problem with Mathematica, When I solve this equation in Mathematica and also in wolframalpha I have different solutions [[image][1][image]

```
a'[t]^2 - A a[t] a'[t] - B a[t]^2 + F = 0

DSolve[y'[x]^2 - A y[x] y'[x] - B y[x]^2 + F == 0, y, x]
```

`Log(F - B a^2)` vs `Log(B a^2 - F)` ??!!

Comment: People here generally like users to post code as *Mathematica* code instead of just images or TeX, so they can copy-paste it. It makes it convenient for them and more likely you will get someone to help you.  You may find [the meta Q&A, How to copy code from Mathematica so it looks good on this site,](http://meta.mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/1584) helpful

Comment: Log(F-B a^2) and Log(B a^2-F) differ by a constant.  Maybe it doesn't matter?

Comment: the difference is the negative sign! Michael E2

Comment: Yes, exactly. If it's the last term in the W|A output that you are pointing out, then the difference of a constant $i\pi$ does not matter because of the arbitrary constant $c_1$ on the other side of the equation.  (If you mean some other term, I don't know what it is.)

Comment: Please make sure that code is contained in code blocks (for readability), and state your question explicitly. There is no explicit question in this post. Please also edit the tags, and use only relevant ones. Is your question related to plotting in any way? To exporting data?

Comment: I need to plot the inverse of this solution